# Remove NA values for prop.table

Tags: r

**I solved this whilst drafting. I am posting it in case someone else needs help with it (solution below) However, it would be interesting to get anyone else's opinion on this still**

I am very new to r. I have a vector with 5 levels: c("Unknown", "Less than 2 hours", "2-4 hours", "4-6 hours", "6+ hours"). It is important that I keep the 'Unknown' level for general analysis, but I want to remove it temporarily to view a prop table without the NAs skewing the percentages.

My current code would be:

```
prop.table(table(x)

 ###  Unknown Less than 2 hours         2-4 hours         4-6 hours          6+ hours 
     0.0002766941      0.4163692206      0.3599789713      0.1509642788      0.0724108353
```

I had tried to directly omit them within the prop.table using code such as:

```
prop.table(x[x %in% c('Less than 2 hours', '2-4 hours', '4-6 hours', '6+ hours')])

prop.table(table(factor(tgi.model$hourswatching_TV), exlude = "Unknown"))
```

...But it does not seem to work at all. Secondly, I tried converted the unknown level into an actual NA before using an na.omit or na.replace. This also did not work, using the code below.

```
x <- factor(c("Unknown", "Less than 2 hours", "2-4 hours", "4-6 hours", "6+ hours"))
levels(x)[levels(x)=='Unknown'] <- NA

na.omit(x)
is.numeric(na.omit(x))
```

I have tried multiple ways to remove the entries once converted to NA, but none of them seem to work. Perhaps it is a formatting issue?

**Solution**
Classic error of missing one word. the first code I had outlined above was simply missing a table() within the formula.

```
prop.table(table(x[x %in% c('Less than 2 hours', '2-4 hours', '4-6 hours', '6+ hours')]))

 ###  Unknown Less than 2 hours         2-4 hours         4-6 hours          6+ hours 
       0.00000000        0.57857722        0.24993238        0.11604003        0.05545037
```

Be sure to let me know if you have a more effective method - perhaps one which removes the unknown column from the output could be better?

Comment: 1) Instead of a long `%in%`, why not the shorter `table(x[x != "Unknown"])`? 2) to assign `NA`, I would have run `is.na(x) <- x == "Unknown"`.